# Unable to uplaod a csv file into oracle table

Tags: oracle, csv

Can someone help me with this issue.

I am able to upload a csv file in the dev database. And then I connected to test database, tried to upload the same csv file into a newly created table but it is not happening.

The steps I have followed are :

i) Right click on table and selected the csv file(data is showing in preview)

ii) When I click on next, it was hanging. I am not able to select the type of insert and it is not going to back step also
[image]

What may be the issue?

Comment: what is the size of your csv file?

Comment: it is lessthan 100kb

Comment: if you post your question to multiple forums, where would you prefer to continue the conversation? what version of SQLDev are you running? if you cut your csv file down to 1 or 100 rows, does it work then? Does it work for ANY csv input?

Comment: Is your csv already opened in another application? this causes the problem you described in plsql developer.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith No, Ihave loaded all the rows in the csv file into table successfully in case of Dev database and sql developer version is 3.0.04

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss No, I guess

Comment: i'm guessing you already tried restarting SQLDev and trying again...otherwise sqldev 3 is about 4 or 5 years old, so you may have better luck with version 4.1